# Unwanted extra spaces at HTML tag boundaries when using ImportString

Tags: bugs, import, html, xml

What causes the following unexpected behavior?

```
In[1]:= ImportString["a<span>b</span>c", "HTML"]
Out[1]= "a b c"

In[2]:= ImportString["a<foo>b</foo>c", "HTML"]
Out[2]= "a bc"
```

In both cases, I would expect the returned string to be `"abc"`.

What is the best way to work around it?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what causes the issue (which looks like a bug to me), but I generally find the best way to deal with exerting control over `Import` not doing quit the right thing with HTML is to use the ["XMLObject"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTML.html) element and use ordinary Mathematica functions on it, like so:

```
In[1]:= ImportString@
         ExportString[
          ImportString["a<span>b</span>c", {"HTML", "XMLObject"}] /. 
           XMLElement[
             Except["html" | "body" | "p" | "li" | "table" | "tr" | "td" | 
               "br" | "ul" | "li"], {___}, {stuff___}] :> stuff, "XML"]
Out[1]= "abc"
```

It's kinda cumbersome to round-trip like that, but on the upside it's very flexible.

**EDIT**ed to strip out a wider range of tags.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't for for other known tags (e.g. `<i>...</i>`)

Comment: @ybeltukov yeah, that's an issue; it wouldn't be so hard to fix, but I don't know which tags are (or, perhaps more usefully, **aren't**) supposed to work that way. Google University time, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

[jSoupLink](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/examples/id/2) can be used as a workaround, like this:

```
<< jSoupLink`
html2text[html_] := First@jSoupLink`ParseHTMLFragment[
   "<div id=\"container\">" <> html <> "</div>", "#container", "text"
   ]

html2text["a<span>b</span>c"]
(* Out: abc *)

html2text["a<foo>b</foo>c"]
(* Out: abc *)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can import raw text and use [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/RemoveTagsFromImportedHTML.html) to remove HTML tags

```
StringReplace[  #, "<" ~~ Except[">"] .. ~~ ">" -> ""] &@
 ImportString["a<bar>b</bar>c", {"HTML", "Source"}]
(* "abc" *)
```